# Query based on date filtering client side

Tags: query, jquerymobile

I was trying to query based on date filtering via client side ( jquery Mobile or ajax toolkit even). I want to pass the HTML input text ( in which user will enter date ) to query ( i tried converting it into javascript date object that didn't work ). I'm using jquery Mobile for building hybrid remote app where i need to query data based on date.

for ex consider querying contacts :

```
Contacts.fetch('soql','SELECT id, firstName, lastName, phone from Contact' + ,function() {
                showContacts(Contacts.data());
            });
```

Above example is taken from jquery mobile sample page but i'm not able to find a way so that in query date filtering can be used.

P.S : i'm using HTML text for input date ( using external plugins ). Reason being i want to avoid the controller

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The passed date must respect SFDC [`Date Formats and Date Literals`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm):

```
Format     |   Format Syntax   |   Example Date only
-----------+-------------------+---------------------
Date only  |   YYYY-MM-DD      |   1999-01-01
```

So in your case (the date only) i would write a simple function that formats the given date to the SFDC date format (assuming a user has entered a correct date):

```
function convertDate(theDate) {
    var newDate = new Date(theDate);
    var today = newDate;
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = today.getDate();
    if(month < 10)
        month = '0' + month;
    if(day < 10)
        day = '0' + day;
    return  year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
}
```

Now you can use this function in your ajax toolkit's query:

```
<script>
function readAccounts(){ 
    var userDate = convertDate(document.getElementById('inputDate').value);
    result = sforce.connection.query('Select Id From Account Where MyDate__c > ' + userDate);
    ...
}
</script>

Date: <input type="text" id="inputDate" />
```

Comment: +1 for the ISO format. The other ways to convert dates to ISO strings in JavaScript are `someDate.toISOString()` for Date/Time values and `someDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10)` for Dates.